# Granting more rights to www-data

Tags: 18.04, permissions, nginx

I've got a .NET Core 3.1 application running on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS box.

Right now, it runs with the account `www-data`. Although this may be a group too, not sure. I understand this is a "passwordless" account and should not be granted root access and the application should NOT run with root credentials either.

I would like my application to be able to write in the directory it is installed (`/var/www/myservice`).

What are best practices to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to make owner of that folder:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/myservice
```

It's more secure, than adding writing permissions to others: `sudo chmod -R o+w /var/www/myservice`